# Is it possible to set or alter the property of an style resource in code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, staticresource

On my xaml page I have severel buttons which uses the same style.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NumberButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        ::
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="183" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="130" />
        ::
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


<Button Style="{StaticResource NumberButtonStyle}" Click="NumberButtonClick" CommandParameter="1">1</Button>
```

Is it possible to set the width of the buttons without setting the value on each button?

(The width is calculated using the screenresolution in code-behind)

Comment: Why not just set a Max and Min value and the layout do that for you?

Comment: I'm creating a numeric keyboard and want the keys to be of equal size... I havn't tried if the columndefinition width="auto" can do it for me - but i doubt. Does the min- and maxwidth flow the controls equally?

Comment: If your layout is done correctly from the start you wouldn't have to do things like babysit widths etc from code behind. `Auto` allows a cell to only take up the space it needs, setting no width on your column allows it to adjust to the space available.